# Visual Studio 2008 : Turn off css class verification

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, validation

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio 2008 from checking whether css classes exist when editing pages and user controls?
It seems ridiculous to put dummy stylesheets on every single user control.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The only way to disable it is to turn off HTML Validation:

Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Validation

Uncheck the "Show Errors" check box.

Answer (score 20):

Yes there is a way.  Go to Tools>Options->Text Editor->CSS->Css Specific

There is an option fgroup here called Errors with 3 check boxes.

- Detect Errors
- Detect Unknown Properties
- Detect Invalid Values

Hope this Helps,

Andrew :-)

Comment: To make it quicker to turn on an off, instead of going through the menu also.  You could record a macro to quickly turn on and off.

Comment: Hi, sorry this simply doesn't work for me. I still have squiggly lines under all of my css class names.

Comment: Ok, then aswell, try going into the HTML node which is directly after the CSS node, in the same settings, expand and hit validation, change the target and try that.  I cannot guarantee you can turn off the squiggly lines, but it will suppress the warnings and errors